# Does swallowing a whole creature fall under Evar Min Hachai?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, animals, evar-min-hachai

Following the deleted question: ["swallowing-permitted-species-alive"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99814/halachic-considerations-on-swallowing-permitted-species-alive),

If one swallows a small fish or a bird or [a Kosher grasshopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosher_locust) whole and alive, does he transgress Evar Min Hachai? If yes how many of transgressions - according to the counting of organs?

I read [Rambam and Chinuch](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94:%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99) but probably missed the answer...

Answer (score 4):

There is no issue of *ever min hachai* with fish or grasshoppers. The gemara in [Chulin 101b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.101b.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes

> The prohibition of eating a limb from a living animal applies whether
>   the limb comes from a domesticated animal (*beheima*), an undomesticated animal (*chaya*),
>   or a bird, and whether it is from a non-kosher species or from a
>   kosher species

See also Rambam MT [Ma'achalot Assurot 5:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968261/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-5.htm). This is codified by the Rema in [SA YD 13:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.13?lang=bi) who permits eating a limb of a live fish but forbids eating a whole live fish as it is disgusting.

Eating a whole bird alive is forbidden by the [Rema](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.13?lang=bi) above. The Rambam (e.g., [in 5:3](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968261/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-5.htm)) never suggests multiple counts of lashes for eating more than an olive-sized portion, therefore it appears there would be only one count of lashes for an entire animal. However, as with eating pork, each additional *kazayit* adds to the weigh of the *issur*.

Comment: Is that one count of בל תשקצו for the whole animal?

Answer (score -1):

The Shulchan Aruch ([YD 100:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.100.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) seems to draw a distinction between a "בריה" (a whole animal) and "ואבר מן החי" by listing them as separate distinct entities:

> "**בריה** דהיינו כגון נמלה או עוף טמא וגיד הנשה **ואבר מן החי** וביצה שיש בה אאפרוח וכיוצא בהם"
>
> "**A creature** (that is, something like an ant or an unkosher bird, or a sciatic nerve, **or a limb of a living animal**, or an egg with a chick inside, and such things)"

If we extend this inference- ie since the Shulchan Aruch seems to list a "בריה" and "אבר מן החי"  as separate entities- perhaps we can suggest that אבר מן החי **wouldn't apply** to a living creature that was eaten whole.

**NOTE:** This suggestion presupposes that the SA is referring to a living creature either dead/alive. If the SA is **only** referring to a dead creature, this line of reasoning may not  work.